# How can I clean emoji data form pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, emoji

Hi guys can you please help me?

1. How can I remove emoji
2. How can I remove tag name (@xxxxx) in message column
3. How can I remove URL

[image]

I can remove the emoji, but the entire sentence in the cell disappeared.

```
df['message'] = df1['Post Title'].str.replace(r'[시x00-Ix7F],, regex=True)
```

Comment: Please don't post data as text, use the output `df.head().to_dict('list')` to provide a sample of your data as plain text.

Comment: 1- provide a [mre], 2- make sure to search the existing questions, 3- **one** problem per question.

Comment: There is no column `'Post Title'` in the data you have provided,